# Remove n elements after each element in a python list

Tags: python, list

I want to remove `n` elements after each element in a list.
Example with `n = 7`:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]  # unmodified list
[1, 9, 17]  # final list
```

I tried this approach but it failed, removing every alternate element from the list for some reason.

```
# cases is a list with over 600 numbers
case_count = 0
case_index = 0

for case in cases:
    print(case_count)
    print(case_index)
    if case_count != 7:
        popped = cases.pop(case_index)
        print(case_index)
        case_count += 1
    else:
        print("Case count equal to 7")
        case_count = 0
    case_index += 1
```

Comment: Looks like you index case_count if case count != 7, then you index it again after. I imagine you want a tab on the else index. (I would just remove the index on the if and always index after)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, basically you want to slice every eighth element?

```py
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
l[0::8]
```

output: `[1, 9, 17]`

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 7
[arr[i] for i in range(0, len(arr), n + 1)]
# [1, 9, 17]
```